# Solution to O.D.E. is periodic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Consider the following ODE:
\begin{cases}
y''(x)=-y(x)^3 \\
y(0)=1 \\
y'(0)=0
\end{cases}
I have to prove that the solution is periodic.

I showed that the quantity $\frac{1}{2}\left (y'(x))^2+\frac{1}{4}(y(x)\right)^4$ is constant and equal to $\frac{1}{4}$, so both $y$ and $y'$ are bounded whenever they are defined, hence $y$ is well defined for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I noticed also that $\tilde{y}(x)=y(-x)$ satisfies the same equation of $y$, so $y$ and $\tilde{y}$ coincide. However, I didn't succeed in proving that $y$ is periodic.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: you mean :
$$\dfrac{1}{2} (y'(x))^2 + \dfrac{1}{4} (y(x))^4$$
is constant.

Comment: Yes, thank you, of course it was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: You can solve this equation easily. You can consider $y'=p$ and $y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy} p$, and then solve it by separation of variable.

Comment: You can prove, using concavity, that :
$$\exists a > 0, y(a) = 1$$
then, by the constant you mentioned $y'(a) = 0$ and we deduce that both $y$ and $y(x + a)$ are solutions of the same problem. $y$ is then $a$-periodic.

Comment: @Essaidi what do you mean when you say "using concavity"?

Comment: $y$ is bounded then it can't remain convex or concave on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does the approach given here answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920545/periodic-solutions-level-sets?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Essaidi ok, but why does it imply that exists $a>0$ such that $y(a)=1$?

Comment: you will have maximum in a certain $a > 0$ then $y'(a) = 0$ and by the constant you found $y(a) = 1$.